# Стилистика

Tags: стилистика

В каком предложении не нарушена литературная норма:
 1. Всем от меня привет, не пропадайте!
 2.Бабуль, твой волос совсем седой стал!

Comment: Предложите свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 2):

1. Всем от меня привет, не пропадайте! - нет нарушения нормы,неполное предложение+ односоставное, разговорный стиль

2.Бабуль, твой волос совсем седой стал!- смешение стилей: бабуль - разговорный, волос - терминологическое использование единственнного числа вместо множественного, свойственное научному стилю, а не разговорному.